# Input from hardware keyboard in Cordova (using Angular & Ionic)

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I have some hardware sending input to my app, either by Bluetooth or wired hardware keyboard. At the moment I have a text field taking the input. I need the field to auto-focus when the screen loads, but without haivng the soft keyboard popup on focus.

I've tried autofocus attribute for HTML, but it messes with the view when I'm using Ionic.

I also tried using an angular directive, to focus after 500ms.

```
.directive('focus', function($timeout, $parse, $cordovaKeyboard) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      $timeout(function() {
        element[0].focus(); 
      }, 500);
    }
  }
})
```

Is there a way of focusing without the soft keyboard displaying in both iOS and Android? I need the soft keyboard to popup only when the user clicks on the input field manually.

The other option would be to have a listener for any hardware keyboard inputs - but I can't see any way to do this in Cordova.

Answer (score 1):

The solution for hide/show software keyboard in Ionic framework project is cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard - see it on GitHub: [https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-plugin-keyboard)

Short info is also in Ionic documentation: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/keyboard

*(Text was updated on 7th Jan 2020, because previously recommended extension ionic-plugin-keyboard is deprecated.)*